# Extending a stored procedure (adding a single part to it) by using a parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a 200 line long stored procedure, which gets a parameter 'prmtr',

What I want to do is add an "sql part" to my stored procedure, according to my parameter.

example:

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(
SELECT * FROM table1
) A

IF (my parameter) = a

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM table2
) B
ON A.ID= B.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT  A.* 
FROM    (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    table1
        ) A LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    table2
        ) B ON  @prmt = 'A'
            AND A.ID= B.ID
```

Comment: That works for my question but how about attaching an sql part like "WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM newTable)" , depending on my parameter ?

Comment: You could switch a WHERE statement like `WHERE @prmt <> 'A' OR A.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM newTable)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a query like this - so you have two choices:

- have two separate queries in the SPROC (one for each branch) - OK for two, but doesn't scale very well to more complex combinations
- use dynamic SQL; i.e. build the query in a `varchar(4000)` and use `sp_ExecuteSQL` to invoke it; fairly obviously you can change a *string* to include an extra `'LEFT JOIN ...'` etc.

All that said, though, I *generally* prefer a single SPROC to always return the same schema - it completely messes with most ORM tools if you change the columns based in the parameters. Something to watch...